# Google shows every page of my WordPress site but I only want the home page indexed

Tags: seo, google, wordpress, robots.txt, meta-tags

So to start with, I have Google crawl my (WordPress) website with the search console, now I can see my pages in the search engine. But it shows every page separately. Like my `/contact`, `/services` and `/about`. I really want only to show my homepage. I searched for plugins like *all-in-one SEO* then I stepped over to *Yoast* for the automatic sitemap and `robots.txt`. I also entered disallow for those pages from being crawled in my `robots.txt`. I have set 'Noindex' to all those pages. That also doesn't work.

I have selected private for my pages to see if this changes anything... doesn't work.

Today I have discovered that I also have unwanted URL's that come from nowhere, like: `/category/uncategorized`, `/author/admin` and `/2016/03...`

And for some reason I have for every page that Google shows me the same meta description.

I really want that Google doesn't show these pages, it's really annoying. What can I do?

Comment: So you have a page available from `/about` but you don’t want Google to give this as a result, ever? So people should never be able to find your *About* page by searching in Google (and other search engines?)? -- How long did you wait after changing `robots.txt`, and how long after adding `noindex`?

Comment: So it is really better to let it be like that then? If I search a company, than I don't see the other pages. I see the main page only. So If you go to my main page then you can always click on about, contact,... I've waited a couple of days (3-4) and than rechecked but nothing really happend after changing robots.txt or noindex. Also if I search on google it changes often, sometime there are 3 urls to see, sometime I can see 5 urls... It's really weird. And than those unwanted url's, I don't want that, everyone can see that..

Comment: It is always advisable to allow the search engines to crawl all your main pages. e.g. home, about, services, contact etc. However you can disallow crawling of category pages, e.g. /category/uncategorized or author pages, e.g. /author/admin etc.

Comment: ... I have them disallowed in my robots.txt... but it doesn't change anything, Google still show them, also on those pages contact, services,... I use Noindex from Yoast. Still no result. So what can I do else? Or maybe I do something wrong...

Comment: Keep in mind that search engines do not turn on a dime. They are not real-time. In fact, search engines are notoriously slow. It can take months for a change you make to show up. Depending upon many factors, it can take less time. Minutes even. Any new site will not be updated quickly.

Comment: @zipkundan It sounds like you are on the right track for an answer. This OP is confused and it might help to clarify his confusion if you feel you are able. It does not have to be complicated or lengthy, just clear. Cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

> I have them disallowed in my robots.txt... but it doesn't change anything, Google still show them, also on those pages contact, services,... I use Noindex from Yoast. Still no result. So what can I do else? Or maybe I do something wrong

If you specifically don't want these pages indexed then you should use the `noindex` robots meta tag in the `head` section of the page (or `X-Robots-Tag` HTTP response header).

DO NOT `disallow` them in `robots.txt`. A disallow rule in robots.txt does not necessarily prevent indexing, it prevents that page from being *crawled* by Googlebot. If the page is linked to it can still appear in Google's index. But in this case, it already is indexed.

It will take some time for Google to update its index before these pages are dropped from the SERPs. You can speed up the process by using the URL removal tool in Google Search Console. However, that does seem a bit drastic for these presumably quite innocent pages.

Although *why* you would want to do this is debatable. (Particularly for pages like `/services` - isn't that a primary, content rich page?) Isn't it dependent on what you are searching for that determines whether you see these pages? (Or are you doing a `site:` search?) The fact that you don't see these pages for companies you search for may simply be that the other pages rank higher for the phrase you are searching for. If I search for `about google`, I find Google's "About" page, but otherwise it's a page that doesn't ordinarily get returned in the SERPs.